# Wifi interface drops all packets

Tags: networking, wifi, tcpdump

I have a remote system connected via WiFi to the network. The wifi connection is established correctly and I can ping the gateway. The maintainer of the gateway (3rd party, not accessible for me) confirms this. The device is connected, got an IP, firewall is not active for my MAC.

Yet I do not have internet connection. I tested it with `ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8` and `curl --interface wlan0 -XGET http://example.org` both resulting in timeouts.
I monitored the traffic on wlan0 with `tcpdump -i wlan0` and noticed, that up to 100% of the packages are dropped by interface. **Clarification:** I can see the packets in the tcpdump output, yet ping states 100% packet loss.

My two questions are: Is this the cause for my missing connection? And how can I fix this?

A firewall (iptables / ufw) is not active.

My `uname -a` output is `Linux machine 3.10.104-126 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Nov 29 22:24:16 UTC 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

My WiFi interface is a `Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter` with device ID `0bda:8176`

---

**Update**

@Lenniey I'm not sure I follow. The connection to the network itself is successful (as I get an IP, DHCP configures gateway dns etc and I can ping the gateway successfully).
My device is at 192.168.200.4 (wlan0) and 192.168.1.31 (eth0).
I already did a traceroute, it looks like this:

```
root@device:~# traceroute -i wlan0 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1 192.168.200.254 (192.168.200.254) 7.069 ms 6.961 ms 6.888 ms
 2 ***
 3 ***
(this continues until traceroute gives up)
30 ***
```

My routing table is as follows:

```
root@device:~# route --verbose
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway          Genmask        Flags  Metric  Ref  Use  Iface
default        192.168.1.254    0.0.0.0        UG     100     0    0    eth0
default        192.168.200.254  0.0.0.0        UG     600     0    0    wlan0
link-local     *                255.255.0.0    U      1000    0    0    eth0
192.168.1.0    *                255.255.255.0  U      100     0    0    eth0
192.168.200.0  *                255.255.255.0  U      600     0    0    wlan0
```

@Dennis Nolte I assumed the packages are dropped by the interface because tcpdump said so at after stopping the monitoring. The output was like (random numbers due to bad memory)

```
59 packages captured
59 packages received by filter
 0 packages dropped by kernel
40 packages dropped by interface
```

The packages dropped by interface ranged between zero and all packages. Kernel never dropped packages in my tests. A wireshark screenshot is not possible as it is a device without a screen attached and I'm not even in the same country as the device. So all my attempts to fix the issue are made via SSH over LAN. But the LAN connection is only temporary for maintenance work, the prod connection will be WiFi.

Comment: I have to ask...how do you connect to your remote system if the packets are dropped? But for your problem: try a traceroute and have a look at where it's getting killed. I assume it's an error on your provider's gateway (no NAT, wrong routes, or similar). But check you routing table nonetheless, maybe it's wrong.

Comment: how do you know the packets are dropped by the interface? did you actually check f.e. ifconfig for the TX/RX dropped packages?
wireshark screenshot might help clarify what you think are packages dropped from the interface.
other than that: routing as Lenniey already wrote is a good guess.

Comment: @Lenniey Thanks for your input, I updated the question with traceroute and routing table

Comment: @DennisNolte Thank you for your input too. I updated the question with traceroute and routing table as requested. (I made this second similar comment to notify you as Serverfault only lets me notify one user per comment)

Comment: Well, it looks like the wifi gateway isn't routing your traffic. Either that, or the NAT is broken, or there is a firewall (even if they say there isn't). Some probable causes.

Comment: @Lenniey so do I get this right, this is an issue fully on the 3rd party side (gateway and NAT)? I have to take their word about firewall, NAT etc as all that stuff is managed by them without me having access.
How come then, my packages are displayed in `tcpdump` as `echo reply` but not recognized by `ping`? I'm fairly new to such issues, I never had some before.

Comment: when you get an ICMP reply from your gateway via wifi interface, this means you are connected.
i assume you did something like: tcpdump -nn -v -e -i wlan0 icmp ?

for the dropped by interface packages see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177739/why-are-tcpdump-packets-being-dropped-by-interface

for how i read it i think you can ignore those for now, this really looks like a Firewall issue especially given that this is a Wifi interface, 
think f.e. Authentification via Radius, EAP etc..

Comment: You get a reply from your gateway interface, so that's not the issue, as @DennisNolte stated. So the problem is further down the path.

Comment: Maybe the customer broke the hardware somehow. I can't imagine how this single device can behave so different from all the others we have out there. They all use the same software, same OS, same hardware.
If the new device, fully checked does not work there, I guess their network is to blame.

Comment: Update from the crazy wifi: New device does not work too. :(